# How to Update CName Record At CloudFlare

Tags: hosting, cloudflare, cname

I am trying to using CloudFlare service for my hosting.After changing my domain dns to cloudflare ,My Domain cname record at cloudflare was redirecting my site to a parking page.By mistake i have deleted that but now can not update my cname record.Any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select DNS in the cloudflare topbar: 
   [image: Cloudflare top bar]
2. Edit the name or value of an existing record, or add a new one with the add record function:

[image]

Please update the original question.
But in regards to your question, CNAMES direct to another domain name, never an ip: 
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cname-record/

If the record must point to an IP, you will need to add an A record.

In regards to what the specific values are for your host, you will need to get these from your Host.

Comment: what will be value in first textbox (Name) and 2nd textbox (IPV4 address)?